# Installing MySQL on Red Hat Linux on the remote server without internet using pre-downloaded RPM packages

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm

I am trying to **install MySQL on the Red Hat Linux remote server without the internet**.

**Problem is :** Can't use internet on the server (so cant use 'yum install ..'  commands)

**Solution found:** To pre-download RMP packages required for the MySQL installation and use RPM command to install them respectively. (so I downloaded the *`Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 / Oracle Linux 7 (x86, 64-bit), RPM Bundle (mysql-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar)`*)

But while **installing these RPMs** using

```
rpm -Uvh mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I am getting this **following error** -

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 5.7.9 is needed by mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
        mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.20-1.el7 is needed by mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
        mariadb-server is needed by (installed) akonadi-mysql-1.9.2-4.el7.x86_64
```

Can anyone help me with installing these RPMs with their dependencies with the constraint of no internet on the server? Thanks.

Comment: duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259640/how-to-use-yum-to-get-all-rpms-required-for-offline-use

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to download all listed failed depended packages but prepare to download more packages while you'd be installing them. When installing `mysql-community-server`, start with `mysql-community-client(x86-64)` and `mysql-community-common(x86-64)`, then mariadb-server (interesting it is needed while you install mysql package, they may conflict with each other, do you need akonadi there?).
Installing manually is a pain, you have to download all the dependencies and install before your package.
Instead of rpm you can use yum with localinstall command. You can try to skip packages which later may conflict (mariadb) with --skip-broken, but do this as a last resort.